# C++ Light-weight linux web pass through server

Tags: php, c++, linux, ssl, encryption

I am in a strange situation where I need a mobile app to communicate with my web server in a secure fashion but using normal SSL is not an option due to the cost and the fact that a self-signed certificate is not supported. I have already tried implementing a php tunnel to encrypt my data with RSA as can be seen here [Is a PHP encryption tunnel possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802590/is-a-php-encryption-tunnel-possible), unfortunately the performance of this setup is ridiculous compared to that of normal SSL.

One of my other options is creating a C++ extension for PHP to try and accelerate the cryptography process but I am still not sure about the performance of that and the whole process of creating a C++ extension for PHP seems incredibly daunting.

The final other option I can see is to move my web server to another port and have a small lightweight C++ web server facing port 80 decrypting the HTTP post request and then forwarding the request to the normal web server on the local host where after it will also encrypt the response from the web server.

Does it sound feasible to make this inline server type thing I am thinking about and where can I find any information that would help me, I am for example struggling to find an example small web server for Linux written in C++ and I have no idea what I should do to encrypt only the POST content of a request etc.

If there is a simpler solution please mention it.

PS. I basically want the app to do a POST request to for example http://sub.mysite.com with POST containing paramters "request" and "key". "Request" will for example be "mypage.php?param=value" and "key" will be the public key of the app, both of these parameters will be encrypted with the public key of the server which will ship with the app.

PPS. I am using Nginx server on Arch Linux if it makes any difference...

Comment: Does your App use a login?

Comment: Downvote for giving the appearance of using SSL but then not really doing it right.

Comment: @EugenRieck Yes it does

Comment: Upvote for not doing SSL

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the widely used and battle-proven `mcrypt` PHP extension with AES encryption: This is how it goes, please bear with me, I have to start with the first requests.

- I assume, you have your account passwords salted and hashed in your DB: `passhash=hash(accountsalt+accountpw)`. Account salt and username (or id) are not secret.
- When you connect to your web service first, have the server give back the account salt and the server's current UTC timestamp - none of this is secret, so it can go over simple HTTP
- On the client side, use the server timestamp to calculate or verify your time offset and store it, so for future requests you have access to a client-side UTC timestamp, that is very close to the server's.
- Now ask your user for the password and calculate `passhash=hash(accountsalt+accountpw)` on the client side.
- Generate a random client-side session salt and remember the corrected client timestamp.
- calculate an intermediate: `intermediate=hash(passhash+clientsessionsalt+timestamp)`
- Log on to the server by transmitting client session salt, timestamp and intermediate: The server should check the timestamp to avoid replay attacks, then calculate the server intermediate - it must match the client intermediate. Store it in your session.
- On successfull login, the server must return a server-side session salt (and session ID)

Now we have everything in place and can do the payload requests: I assume the payload is some binary string (e.g. JSON). So for all further requests

- Note the corrected client timestamp.
- On the client, calculate the key: `key=hash(serversessionsalt+timestamp+intermediate)`
- encrypt your payload with the key
- transmit your session ID, timestamp and encrypted payload
- On the server side, check the timestamp, then use it to calculate the same key
- Use this key to decrypt the payload with `mcrypt` - this should be fast.

Some notes:

- If you want, you can introduce a request salt for additional protection against precalculation attacks
- For the same rationale you can have the server change the session salt regularily, but be careful if you use async requests
- The timestamp is crucial: For an attacker to break in, he would need to break the hashes in close to real time, which is not trivial - it is by orders of magnitude harder then breaking it eventually
- While this does not provide you with a proof of identity for the server, it provides you with thze assurance, that the server knows the pass hash: A fake server will be unable to calculate the keys

Comment: Thanks, this seems intricate but I want to encrypt all communication between the server and client preferably with public key encryption for just in case my app gets decompiled (I am forced to make an Android version...)

Comment: @Gerhman - nothing in this is about a key embedded in the appliaction!  We encrypt all **payload**, nothing secret goes out in the clear. Let me repeat and emphasize: Somebody decompiling your App is nowhere nearer to breaking in.